# Mozilla Firefox and Adblock Plus Inquiry

Tags: firefox

I keep getting prompted (in a seperate Window to update Firefox). I initially did so the first time, but it installed software automatically that I don't want. And now, every so often, I get pop ups coming up even after installing AdBlock Plus. I have tried messing around with the settings to block the specific sites but they keep coming up. Does anyone have any suggestions to get rid of these annoying prompts to update?

Comment: Can you give an example of how such a prompt looks like? What's your operating system? Have you done a virus and malware scan yet?

Comment: What 'software' was installed automatically? What is the version of Firefox you are running right now?

Comment: I did a virus scan and there is nothing. One piece of software i remember specifically is webbar (which I removed). One URL that pops up is http://www.directspecialsonline.com/?pid=54&cid=

Comment: I found a way to filter out the other URL with ABP.

Comment: Here is the URL that keeps popping up:http://updatenowpro.com/su/01/39a73a783692bccb52ea0cb5b528fa6bd438468703c3471400418746d3e946c3:1404674366/?filename=setup&b=36c66a2a&sid=54

Comment: Run a *full* (not quick) malware scan with [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) (assuming you are using Windows). It will take a while. Let us know the results. Antivirus software generally doesn't do a great job detecting malware, as viruses are different than "malware". Also be careful what you click. You may also want to check your list of installed programs and explicitly uninstall things that you did not want uninstalled. AdBlock won't help with this and you need to identify the source of these popups and remove it.

Comment: If I get Malware bytes, this will not conflict with Microsoft Security Essentials, will it?

Comment: No, it won't. They both target different things, and you should probably keep using both.

Comment: @Jason C: hat seemed to have worked. You mind posting this as an answer?